# Grid Bootstrap funcionamento

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

porque ao utilizar desta forma funciona:

```
col-3 col-md-3
```

E dessa forma não funciona

```
col-sm-3 col-md-3
```

A primeira forma está correta?

Comment: Mas o que você quer dizer com "funciona"

Comment: Se diminuir o navegador o primeiro exemplo funciona, o segundo não

Comment: O correto é usar ou o "sm" ou o "md", que isso são os tamanhos "small" "medium"

Comment: https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-the-bootstrap-3-grid-system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sua resposta eh mais simples do que parece. Vc esta usando as classes de uma versão do grid no outro. O que quero dizer eh que vc esta usando as classes do grid do Bootstrap 4 no Bootstrap 3. Ai não funciona.

A classe `col-3` não existe no Bootstrap 3, por isso não funciona. Vc pode substituir por `col-xs-3` que eu a menor medida pro grid do BS3

Documentação oficial do grid do **BS3**: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid-options

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Documentação oficial do grid do **BS4**: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#grid-options

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então veja que no **BS3** não existe apenas a classe `col-*` assim como no **BS4** não tem a classe `col-xs-*`

`col-3 col-md-3` funciona apenas no BS4

`col-xs-3 col-md-3` funciona apenas no BS3

`col-sm-3 col-md-3` funciona no BS3 e no BS4

Comment: Realmente kkkkkkkkk vlw mano

Comment: @Banks Tranquilo jovem, cuidado com o google cada hora ele mostra o link pra uma versão do bootstrap ai a gente acaba pegando classes de uma versão e usando na outra, ai pode dar esse tipo de problema. As coisa estamos ai, sucesso!